# Codeigniter displays file structure on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, access-control

I have a setup of Codeigniter in place with a controller called vendors.
I also have a folder called vendors in the root directory of the project.

The problem is whenever I try calling www.example.com/vendors Codeigniter routes to the folder called vendors in the root directory and displays the file structure in the browser.

How can I fix this other than renaming either the controller or the folder.

Shouldn't Codeigniter be looking for a controller only under the controllers folder?

**quote from OP's comment**:

> this happens on localhost (apache 2.4.27 and php 7.1.9 ), works fine on the production server.

Comment: Which web server are you using? You need to turn directory listing in the web server configuration.

Comment: rename your controller to my_vendor....otherwise you'll need a constructor in your controller

Comment: @jfadich happens on localhost, works fine on the production server.

Comment: @Vickel renaming was the last resort as that involves alot of refactoring.Can you tell me a little more about adding a constructor because the controller already has a constructor.

Comment: it's all written here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#reserved-method-names. I'm not 100% sure this applies to your case, hence I didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: @Vickel checked it out and seems to apply to classes and not folders and either ways vendors does not seem to violate and reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

After checking .htaccess and similar I found 2 solutions to **hide a folder on localhost**, but have it's containing files (e.g. images) accessible through a web-page.

**the first** is to add to your root .htacess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

so it would look like this:

```
# DON'T FORGET TO CHANGE $config['index_page'] = '';
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|photos|videos|vendors|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 
Options -Indexes
```

**the second** is to add an empty index.html file into that (vendors) folder.

The file structure is now hidden!

edit: actually, you see that codigniter folders have index.html files which look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first method managed to block viewing of the folder structure and shows a forbidden page but i would like it instead to route to my controller that is called Vendors instead of showing a forbidden page.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, if I take vendors out of the .htaccess and have a controller Vendors.php in my controller folder, it executes its index method. Make sure Vendors.php is uppercase.

Comment: Did you try this on localhost or the server? The controller name has been Vendors since the start. Maybe you have some php configuration that's preventing direct access to file structure?

Comment: on localhost, using easyPhp, php 5.5.0, apache 2.4.4.

Comment: apache 2.4.27 and php 7.1.9 for me.

Comment: what's the production server's configuration?

Comment: apache 2.2 and php version 7.1